# fatal: unable to open include file `system.inc'

Tags: assembly, nasm, freebsd

I am a noob trying to compile his first Assembler program on FreeBSD using the following guide: http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/x86-first-program.html

When I run `nasm -f elf hello.asm`, I get the following error:

`hello.asm:1: fatal: unable to open include file 'system.inc'`

Admittedly I did not install nasm from the ports collection but compiled it from source, in case that makes any difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you skipped the [previous chapter](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/x86-portable-code.html) - see section **11.5.5 Using an Include File**. You just need to copy and paste the various defines etc there into your own `system.inc`.